# What might cause a partially loaded JPEG in a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, imageview, rendering, jpeg

We are getting reports in the field, on both iOS and Android, of partially loaded profile images in our mobile app.

Here is what it looks like (note that I have gaussian blurred part of the image to protect the privacy of our members, but the grey is what is actually rendered):

[image: partially rendered image]

AFAIK there is not a concept of loading "Progressive JPEGS" in UIImageView, so I am at a loss about how this image could even have been rendered at all. This code has not been modified in at least a year. All images are hosted on S3, and have been for 2 years.

Is it somehow possible that carriers are truncating images now if a device hits a certain bandwidth limit?

-- Edit --

I can confirm we were able to repro this behavior on an AT&T network. Is it possible that AT&T is munging images in this fashion when a user goes over his data cap or something?

Comment: I don't think this is AT&T . I am having a similar issue over wireless to a local server. I am changing a displayed image using javascript: document.getElementById('IMG_ID').src="image.JPG";

Comment: After switch to HTTPS we are not reproducing this behavior anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue crop up when I switched from https to http images.  Needless to say... I switched back to https based images.